# How to get a single attribute of a json with Angular request

Tags: angular

I would like to know how can I get a single attribute of a json with an Angular request and map it to an Interface ?
Here are the attributes of the json :

[image]

I would like to map the attribute 'data' to my Interface Card.
Here is my function :

```js
  public getCards(page: number): Observable<Card[]> {
    this.params = this.params.set('page', page);
    return this.http
      .get<Card[]>(`${this.URL}/cards`, {
        headers: this.headers,
        params: this.params,
      })
      .pipe(tap((response) => console.log('response', response)));
  }
```

I hope someone will be able to help, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the RxJS map operator. This will return the selected value of your return and forward it to the next operator. And in your example you took a wrong type for the request. You should have a interface that includes those pagination included. Following exmaple should help you:

Interface:

```
interface WithPagination<T> {
  data: T[];
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  totalCount: number;
}
```

```
  public getCards(page: number): Observable<Card[]> {
    this.params = this.params.set('page', page);
    return this.http
      .get<WithPagination<Card>>(`${this.URL}/cards`, {
        headers: this.headers,
        params: this.params,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response.data)
      );
  }
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error on the 'data' of reponse.data :
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Card[]'

Comment: ah i mislooked your example. Your assigned return type of the  request is wrong. You should have a interface that has those pagination data included like `interface WithPagination { data: unkown[],  page: number, ...}`

Comment: I adjust my answer and that should work for you

Comment: Ohhhh, i didnt know I should do that, thank you very much for your time and your help !!